# mysqldump backup file shows Could not open input file: Mysqldump

Tags: cron, backup, cpanel, database-backups

i have this cron job command below to backup my database in my web server. But when i got the backup file it only shows `Could not open input file: Mysqldump`. What can i do to see the Sql content including my tables and data etc?

```
php mysqldump -u'my_username' -p'my_password' 'my_database_name' > /home/cpaneluser/data/backup_folder/backup_`date +\%d\%m\%y`.sql
```

Comment: because it thinks as mysqldump as php file. If i am right, you have to remove php and run the command

Comment: Thanks dude. i forgot to remove it